# How to install VirtualBox guest additions on Amazon Linux 2 image

Tags: linux, virtualbox

I have been following the instructions at the following link to try and install guest additions onto an Amazon Linux 2 box

https://itekblog.com/centos-7-virtualbox-guest-additions-installation-centos-minimal/

But when I do the

```
./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```

I get the following. Has anyone had any success in getting this to work?

[image]

Comment: Run `yum update kernel` to update the VM and reboot.

Comment: @harrymc spot on and if you do that as an answer rather than a comment I can accept. Thanks!

Comment: Done as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update the kernel and all packages, including kernel-headers,
run the following command and reboot:

```
yum update kernel
```